# Handling current URL inside chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My goal is to check whether the user is currently on a page where its URL starts with "https://swisscom.ch" or not. According to this result, the extension should show me inside chrome, that the page is not "hosted" by swisscom.ch.

But when I am using the method `startsWith()` there are no results. It always goes diretcly into the `else`-Method.
How can I achieve this result?

This is my current code in script.js:

````
async function fetchData() {

    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
    function(tabs){
    
        alert(tabs[0].url.toString())
        if(tabs[0].url.startsWith("https://swisscom.ch")) {
            alert('Dies ist eine gültige Seite der Swisscom (Schweiz) AG.')
            chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "#00FF00"});

        } else {
            alert('Vorsicht! Dies ist keine Seite der Swisscom (Schweiz) AG. Geben Sie keine Login- oder Bankdaten ein.')
            chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "#FF0000"});

        }
    }
 );
}    
fetchData();
```

And this one inside my manifest: 
```
{
    "name": "SCSAG Security Check",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Example App",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "alpinebeagle",
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Check page status"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ] 
}
```
````

Comment: It's `https://www.swisscom.ch/`, see [Chrome address bar no longer shows protocol or www subdomain](https://superuser.com/a/1498561)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you very much! Do you may know how I can achieve to run the check on URL-Change? Saw multiple StackOverflow-Pages but none is working with my code...